# Clique exhaustive-search algorithm

Tags: algorithm

consider the clique problem given a graph g and a positive integer k, determine whether the graph contains a clique of size k, i.e., a complete subgraph of k vertices. design an exhaustive search algorthim for this problem.

The hint to this problem is Follow the definitions of a clique and of an exhaustive-search algorithm.

I know that 1.S has to be assigned a k sized subset. 2. search for an edge in G for every pair of vertices of set S.If that fails go back to step 1 for another k sized subset. Step 3 stop and return success.

This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Why are you stuck? What do you think you should do next?

Comment: From the question I thought I needed to write an algorithm.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Can you outline your thoughts about what to do next? Right now, we can't tell what to help you with.

Comment: Is this the correct answer. Step 1 S has to be assigned a k sized subset. Step 2 Search for an edge in G for every pair of vertices of set S.If that fails go back to step 1 for another k sized subset. Step 3 stop and return success.

Comment: Your question says that you're stuck. Are you stuck because you think you have the right answer, but you're not sure? Or are you stuck because you think what you have is correct, but you're not sure how to prove it?

Comment: I am stuck because I think I have the right answer but I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

As a hint about how to prove that your algorithm is correct:

- If you find a k-sized subset in step (1) where all nodes are connected, can you say for certain that the graph has a k-clique?
- If the graph has a k-clique, can you say for certain that you'll find it in step (1) at some point?

Hope this helps!